# Securing a laptop desk clamp arm in a car?

Tags: interior

https://www.amazon.ca/Mount-Adjustable-Articulating-Computers-MI-4352LT/dp/B01HSJPVV8

(or any other ones on Amazon mods can delete link if you want.)

I am looking to get a metal laptop holder and the ones that clamp to a desk are around 60$ instead of 250$ for ones made for a car.

What would be a good base to secure it to on the passenger side floor? I was thinking of a patio umbrella holder

Comment: In an accident an unsecured laptop is going to become a heavy flying object that could hurt people, you need to use something that will keep it from flying around.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair, and is thus off-topic.

Comment: Ask your local police to examine how they mount police computers in vehicles. You can get some ideas from their secure mounts then search for availability and/or create your own, keeping safety in mind in personal vehicles.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that stand is totally unsuitable for use in a car - it has no way to secure the laptop, and has sharp edges. In the event of a crash,the laptop would fly around the car, and you could easily injure yourself or your passenger on the stand - especially if it got in the way of an airbag. A patio umbrella stand would be even worse, adding a heavy loose object to the mix!

I'd suggest getting a proper in car one that is type-approved by an appropriate safety body, which holds the laptop securely, and is positioned such that the screen isn't visible to the driver when the car is moving (e.g. angled towards the passenger) to avoid distraction.